# UDP port unreachable although process is listening

Tags: netcat, udp, icmp

I am experimenting with communication over UDP port 6666 (the goal is setting up a listener for netconsole, but that's not really relevant here).

On the listening side, `nc -luv 6666`.
On the sending side, `nc -uv LISTENER_IP 6666`. I can send and receive, life is good.

Now I leave the listener running, but kill the sender and start another sender. It terminates immediately. A network trace reveals that the receiving server sends an *ICMP Port Unreachable*. However, the listener still listens:

```
$ sudo ss -nlup|grep 6666
UNCONN     0      0           :::6666                    :::*                   users:(("nc",pid=3417,fd=3))
```

I kill the receiver and run a new one. Everything works as before until I kill the sender.

Sender and receiver are physical machines on the same network. The same test between a physical machine and a VM running on it yields the same result.

How can this behaviour be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way that UDP "connections" work, this is expected behaviour. This is discussed [in the `nc6(1)` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nc6&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE+and+Portsb) ("UDP"), but is applicable to `socat` and `nc` as well:

> UDP support in netcat6  works very well in both connect and in listen
>   mode. When using UDP in listen mode netcat6 accepts UDP packets from
>   any source that matches the optional address and/or port specified (if
>   it was specified).  However, once the first packet is received,
>   netcat6 will only receive packets from that client in future. This is
>   done by putting the UDP socket into "connected" state (see udp(4) and
>   connect(2)). Packets from other sources are discarded by the kernel
>   and an ICMP unreachable response is sent.
>
> When  connecting to a remote host using UDP, nc6 will report that the
>   connection is open regardless of whether a remote server is listening.
>   This is because UDP is a connectionless protocol, and hence no
>   connection establishment is actually required. However, after sending
>   the first packet of data, a server may reply with an ICMP unreachable
>   response causing nc6 to exit with a 'Connection refused' error
>   message.

When you connect from the sender side, a random UDP source port is chosen. The receiver then binds to that particular `host:port` pair and will not listen to any other connection from then on. To solve this, you need to force the sender to always use the same port. I used `socat` for this example because it was easier to do:

Listener:

```
# socat -d -d UDP-LISTEN:6666 stdout
2018/01/29 22:02:02 socat[20969] N listening on UDP AF=2 0.0.0.0:6666
2018/01/29 22:02:07 socat[20969] N accepting UDP connection from AF=2 10.100.0.5:39000
2018/01/29 22:02:07 socat[20969] N using stdout for reading and writing
2018/01/29 22:02:07 socat[20969] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [1,1]
hello
bye
hello1
bye1
```

Sender:

```
# socat -d -d stdin UDP:listener-host:6666
2018/01/29 22:01:56 socat[8237] N using stdin for reading and writing
2018/01/29 22:01:56 socat[8237] N opening connection to AF=2 10.100.0.3:6666
2018/01/29 22:01:56 socat[8237] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.100.0.5:39000
2018/01/29 22:01:56 socat[8237] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [0,0] and [5,5]
hello
bye
2018/01/29 22:02:10 socat[8237] N socket 1 (fd 0) is at EOF    
2018/01/29 22:02:10 socat[8237] N exiting with status 0
```

```
# socat -d -d stdin UDP:listener-host:6666
2018/01/29 22:02:13 socat[8238] N using stdin for reading and writing
2018/01/29 22:02:13 socat[8238] N opening connection to AF=2 10.100.0.3:6666
2018/01/29 22:02:13 socat[8238] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.100.0.5:57125
2018/01/29 22:02:13 socat[8238] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [0,0] and [5,5]
hello
2018/01/29 22:02:16 socat[8238] E read(5, 0x5619f9b09330, 8192): Connection refused
2018/01/29 22:02:16 socat[8238] N exit(1)
```

```
# socat -d -d stdin UDP:listener-host:6666,sourceport=39000
2018/01/29 22:05:17 socat[8280] N using stdin for reading and writing
2018/01/29 22:05:17 socat[8280] N opening connection to AF=2 10.100.0.3:6666
2018/01/29 22:05:17 socat[8280] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.100.0.5:39000
2018/01/29 22:05:17 socat[8280] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [0,0] and [5,5]
hello1
bye1
2018/01/29 22:05:23 socat[8280] N socket 1 (fd 0) is at EOF
2018/01/29 22:05:24 socat[8280] N exiting with status 0
```

As you can see, the source port changed on the sender but if I forced it to reuse the same port it worked.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense and it works. Thanks!  Just by the way, _netcat_ (or _nc_ as its friends call it) needs the _-p_ option to set the source port on the sender side, and of course you can use _ss_ or _netstat_ on the listener side to find out what that source port is.